# CSS -calc() or JQuery calc() not working for top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four absolute positioned divs on the screen which need to maintain their positions in a ratio at all the resolutions.

div1 - height 150px, top 0px

div2 - height 30%, top 150px

div3 - height 50px, top (30% + 150px)

div 4 - height (70% - 200px), top (30% + 200px)

**Working**

```
   var calcHeight;
   calcHeight = attr["@value"].split('+');
   $CompFrame.css('height', calcHeight[0].trim()).css('height', "+=" + calcHeight[1].trim());
```

**Not Working**

```
var calcTop;
  calcTop = attr["@value"].split('+');
  $CompFrame.css('top', calcTop[0].trim()).css('top', "+=" + calcTop[1].trim());
```

Code for "-" is also present
**I can't use floats due to design reasons**

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work. The jquery calc() implementation